# html form how to make sure it is being called from my domain

Tags: php, forms, security, authentication

I have a html form post. anyone on the web can access the page and submit the form,

but how can I be sure that the form was submitted using my page? you problem you that anyone can snif over the network, check the http post request and replicate it

my issue is that i don't have users, so really anyone can access the page, but i want the form to be submitted using my page

what are my option?

my server side is php

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWje5DWniDQ

Answer (score -1):

you can send visitors a cookie with a view, and have the server only accept form submissions from clients with a cookie.

Comment: No! That just tests to see if the form was posted by a browser that has visited the site recently.

Comment: Alright, you got me!